# Delete a line when ticks are clicked - d3js

Tags: d3.js

I have two y-axis with time as data.
I am trying to add and delete a line when ticks are clicked on the respective axis.
Lines are getting generated but not sure how to remove the lines. i tried using

```js
 svg.data([thisData]).remove('line')
```

but that removes the chart completely.

**MORE DETAILS**
there is 1-1 relationship between ticks of respective axis.

```js
var data = [{
   "inTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00",
   "outTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00"
 }, {
   "inTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00",
   "outTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00"
 }, {
   "inTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00",
   "outTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00"
 }, {
   "inTime": "2013-04-26T00:00:00-05:00",
   "outTime": "2013-04-26T00:00:00-05:00"
 },
 ];

 var margin = {
     top: 40,
     right: 40,
     bottom: 40,
     left: 40
   },
   width = 600,
   height = 700;

 //Define Left Y axis
 var y = d3.time.scale()
   .domain([new Date(data[0].inTime), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].inTime), 1)])
   .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

 //Define Right Y axis

 var y1 = d3.time.scale()
   .domain([new Date(data[1].inTime), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].outTime), 1)])
   .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);


 //Left Yaxis attributes
 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(y)
   .orient('left')
   .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m/%d %H:%M'))
   .tickSize(8)
   .tickPadding(8);


 //Right Yaxis attributes       
 var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(y1)
   .orient('right')
   .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m/%d %H:%M'))
   .tickSize(8)
   .tickPadding(8);


 //Create chart
 var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
   .attr('class', 'chart')
   .attr('width', width)
   .attr('height', height)
   .append('g')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');
 


 //Add left Yaxis to group
 svg.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'y axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(100,   5)')
   .call(yAxis);

 //Add right Yaxis to group
 svg.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'x axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(400,   1)')
   .call(yAxisRight);


 var parse = d3.time.format('%m/%d %H:%M');


 //Function to add a line between two ticks
 function addLine(t1, t2) {
   var ticks = {};
   d3.selectAll('.tick text').each(function(d) {
     ticks[d3.select(this).text()] = this;
   });

   var pos1 = ticks[t1].getBoundingClientRect();
   var pos2 = ticks[t2].getBoundingClientRect();

   svg.append('line')
     .attr('x1', pos1.top - pos1.width)
     .attr('y1', pos1.top + 5)
     .attr('x2', pos2.left - 5)
     .attr('y2', pos2.top + 5)
     .style('stroke', 'black')
 }

 var ticks = svg.selectAll(".tick");
 ticks.attr('class', function(d, i) {
   return 'ticks' + i;
 }).each(function(d, i) {
   d3.select(this).append("circle")
     .attr('id', function(d) {
       return 'tickCircle' + i;
     })
     .attr('class', function(d) {
       return 'tickCircles' + this.id
     })
     .attr("r", 5)
     .on('click', function(d) {
     console.log('clicked')
       return addLineNew(this);
     })
     .on('mouseover', function(d){
           d3.select(this).style('fill','red'); })
           
           .on('mouseout', function(d){
           d3.select(this).style('fill','black'); })
           });

 ticks.selectAll("line").remove();

 var firstTick;
 var secondTick;
 var secondTickMap={};
 var firstTickMap={};
 var allLines=[];
 //add Line
 function addLineNew(element) {
   if (firstTick && secondTick) {
     firstTick = '';
     secondTick = '';
   }
   if (!firstTick || firstTick === '') {
     firstTick = element.id
   } 
   else if ((secondTick != 'undefined' || secondTick === '') && !(secondTick in firstTickMap)) {
     secondTick = element.id
   }

   if (firstTick && secondTick) {
    
    if(firstTick == secondTick){
     if(firstTick in firstTickMap){delete firstTickMap.firstTick;}
     else if(firstTick in secondTickMap){delete secondTickMap.firstTick;}
     if(secondTick in firstTickMap){delete firstTickMap.secondTick;}
     else if(secondTick in secondTickMap ){delete secondTickMap.secondTick;}
    }
   if(!(firstTick in firstTickMap) && !(secondTick in secondTickMap) && !(firstTick in secondTickMap) && !(secondTick in firstTickMap))
    {
  var firstTickBBox = getBBox(firstTick)
     var secondTickBBox = getBBox(secondTick);
     var firstTickPos = getCenterPoint(firstTickBBox);
     var secondTickPos = getCenterPoint(secondTickBBox);
  firstTickMap[firstTick] = firstTick;
  secondTickMap[secondTick] = secondTick;
     createLine(firstTickPos, secondTickPos)
    }
    }
 }
 
 
 //get Center Point
 function getCenterPoint(element) {
   var thisX = element.left + element.width / 2;
   var thisY = element.top + element.height / 2;

   return [thisX, thisY]
 }

 function getBBox(element) {
   var thisEl = document.getElementById(element).getBoundingClientRect();
   return thisEl;
 }

 //create a line between pointA and pointB
 function createLine(pointA, pointB) {
 
   var thisData = {
     x1: pointA[0],
     y1: pointA[1],
     x2: pointB[0],
     y2: pointB[1]
   };

   allLines.push(svg.data([thisData]).append('line')
     .attr('x1', function(d) {
     console.log(d)
       return d.x1;
     })
     .attr('y1', function(d) {
       return d.y1;
     })
     .attr('x2', function(d) {
       return d.x2;
     })
     .attr('y2', function(d) {
       return d.y2;
     }).style('stroke', 'black')
     .style('stroke-width','1')
     .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (-margin.left - 5) + ', ' + (- margin.top - 5) + ')'));
     
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: would you not rather just click on the line to delete the line ? Or say double click on it so you dont get mixed up ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy sure click or double click should also work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off lets clear a couple of things up. When you create the line you push your array of lines to an array like so :

```
allLines.push(svg.data([thisData]).append('line')...
```

This is not the correct way to do it. The best way to do it is, when you  create a line, push that lines data, e.g x1,y1,x2,y2 etc to an array and use this array to create all the lines at once. This is how D3 works.

So I changed your functions around.

```
function createLine(pointA, pointB) {

  var thisData = {
    x1: pointA[0],
    y1: pointA[1],
    x2: pointB[0],
    y2: pointB[1]
  };

  allLinesData.push(thisData) //push points into array
  drawLines(allLinesData); //draw all lines at once from 'allLinesData'
}
```

Function to draw lines :

```
function drawLines(data) { //pass the data you want
  var line = svg.selectAll('.line').data(data);

  line.enter().append('line')
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {return 'genLine' + i; })
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.x1;})
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.y1; })
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.x2; })
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.y2; })
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('stroke-width', '3')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) { d3.select(this).style('stroke', 'red') })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) { d3.select(this).style('stroke', 'black') })
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (-margin.left - 5) + ', ' + (-margin.top - 5) + ')')

  line.on('dblclick', function(d) { //delete line
    var thisLine = this;

    line.each(function(e, i) {
      var thisLine2 = this;
      if (thisLine.id === thisLine2.id) {
        console.log('splice')
          allLinesData.splice(i--, 1); //remove from array you use to feed the line drawer
        d3.select(this).remove(); //remove it from DOM
      }
        })
  })
  line.exit().remove(); //remove unwanted lines

}
```

Also added on 'mouseover' so you know what line youre on.

Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/vr09w905/1/

Also if you just want it here :

```js
var data = [{
  "inTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00",
  "outTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00"
}, {
  "inTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00",
  "outTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00"
}, {
  "inTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00",
  "outTime": "2013-04-24T00:00:00-05:00"
}, {
  "inTime": "2013-04-26T00:00:00-05:00",
  "outTime": "2013-04-26T00:00:00-05:00"
}, ];

var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 600,
  height = 700;

//Define Left Y axis
var y = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date(data[0].inTime), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].inTime), 1)])
  .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

//Define Right Y axis

var y1 = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date(data[1].inTime), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].outTime), 1)])
  .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);


//Left Yaxis attributes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient('left')
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m/%d %H:%M'))
  .tickSize(8)
  .tickPadding(8);


//Right Yaxis attributes       
var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y1)
  .orient('right')
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m/%d %H:%M'))
  .tickSize(8)
  .tickPadding(8);


//Create chart
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'chart')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');



//Add left Yaxis to group
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(100,   5)')
  .call(yAxis);

//Add right Yaxis to group
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(400,   1)')
  .call(yAxisRight);


var parse = d3.time.format('%m/%d %H:%M');


//Function to add a line between two ticks
function addLine(t1, t2) {
  var ticks = {};
  d3.selectAll('.tick text').each(function(d) {
    ticks[d3.select(this).text()] = this;
  });

  var pos1 = ticks[t1].getBoundingClientRect();
  var pos2 = ticks[t2].getBoundingClientRect();

  svg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', pos1.top - pos1.width)
    .attr('y1', pos1.top + 5)
    .attr('x2', pos2.left - 5)
    .attr('y2', pos2.top + 5)
    .style('stroke', 'black')
}

var ticks = svg.selectAll(".tick");
ticks.attr('class', function(d, i) {
  return 'ticks' + i;
}).each(function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).append("circle")
    .attr('id', function(d) {
      return 'tickCircle' + i;
    })
    .attr('class', function(d) {
      return 'tickCircles' + this.id
    })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .on('click', function(d) {
      console.log('clicked')
      return addLineNew(this);
    })
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style('fill', 'red');
    })

  .on('mouseout', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style('fill', 'black');
  })
});

ticks.selectAll("line").remove();

var firstTick;
var secondTick;
var secondTickMap = {};
var firstTickMap = {};
//var allLines = [];
var allLinesData = [];
//add Line
function addLineNew(element) {
  if (firstTick && secondTick) {
    firstTick = '';
    secondTick = '';
  }
  if (!firstTick || firstTick === '') {
    firstTick = element.id
  } else if ((secondTick != 'undefined' || secondTick === '') && !(secondTick in firstTickMap)) {
    secondTick = element.id
  }

  if (firstTick && secondTick) {

    if (firstTick == secondTick) {
      if (firstTick in firstTickMap) {
        delete firstTickMap.firstTick;
      } else if (firstTick in secondTickMap) {
        delete secondTickMap.firstTick;
      }
      if (secondTick in firstTickMap) {
        delete firstTickMap.secondTick;
      } else if (secondTick in secondTickMap) {
        delete secondTickMap.secondTick;
      }
    }
    if (!(firstTick in firstTickMap) && !(secondTick in secondTickMap) && !(firstTick in secondTickMap) && !(secondTick in firstTickMap)) {
      var firstTickBBox = getBBox(firstTick)
      var secondTickBBox = getBBox(secondTick);
      var firstTickPos = getCenterPoint(firstTickBBox);
      var secondTickPos = getCenterPoint(secondTickBBox);
      firstTickMap[firstTick] = firstTick;
      secondTickMap[secondTick] = secondTick;
      createLine(firstTickPos, secondTickPos)
    }
  }
}


//get Center Point
function getCenterPoint(element) {
  var thisX = element.left + element.width / 2;
  var thisY = element.top + element.height / 2;

  return [thisX, thisY]
}

function getBBox(element) {
  var thisEl = document.getElementById(element).getBoundingClientRect();
  return thisEl;
}

//create a line between pointA and pointB
function createLine(pointA, pointB) {

  var thisData = {
    x1: pointA[0],
    y1: pointA[1],
    x2: pointB[0],
    y2: pointB[1]
  };

  allLinesData.push(thisData) //push points into array
  drawLines(allLinesData); //draw all lines at once from 'allLinesData'
}


function drawLines(data) { //pass the data you want
  var line = svg.selectAll('.line').data(data);

  line.enter().append('line')
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
      return 'genLine' + i;
    })
    .attr('x1', function(d) {
      return d.x1;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return d.y1;
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return d.x2;
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return d.y2;
    })
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('stroke-width', '3')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style('stroke', 'red')
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style('stroke', 'black')
    })
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (-margin.left - 5) + ', ' + (-margin.top - 5) + ')')

  line.on('dblclick', function(d) { //delete line
    var thisLine = this;

    line.each(function(e, i) {
      var thisLine2 = this;
      if (thisLine.id === thisLine2.id) {
        console.log('splice')
        allLinesData.splice(i--, 1); //remove from array you use to feed the line drawer
        d3.select(this).remove(); //remove it from DOM
      }
    })
  })
  line.exit().remove(); //remove unwanted lines

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help..i was able to delete based on ticks..but your approach looks way cleaner..